# Example for replacement for InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()

Tags: android, junit, android-instrumentation

With AndroidX the InstrumentationRegistry is now deprecated. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/InstrumentationRegistry#getContext()) states

> This method is deprecated. In most scenarios, getApplicationContext() should be used instead of the instrumentation test context. If you do need access to the test context for to access its resources, it is recommended to use getResourcesForApplication(String) instead.

However, I cannot find any examples of how to obtain the instance of `PackageManager` in test to invoke `getResourcesForApplication` and which package name should be provided to its string parameter.

For instance, here is the code that currently works:

```java
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void processImage() {
        // load image from test assets
        AssetManager am = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext().getAssets();
        InputStream is = null;
        Bitmap image = null;
        try {
            is = am.open("image.jpg");
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if ( is != null ) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) { }
            }
        }

        assertNotNull(image);

        // do something with the image
    }
}
```

Now, how to rewrite this test without using the deprecated `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()`? Keep in mind that `image.jpg` is not part of the application's assets - it's located in `src/androidTest/assets` folder and gets packaged into `AppName-buildType-androidTest.apk` (it's not present in the `AppName-buildType.apk`, for which I know the package name).

How to deduce the package name of the test APK? Is it possible to avoid hardcoding package name strings in my unit test? I am looking for a solution that is as elegant as the original code, but does not use deprecated methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simply use `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets()` instead of `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext().getAssets()`.

It will use your test context, so you should get your assets.